# Входная строка имела не верный формат

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Выдает ошибку что входная строка имела не верный формат.  Если ячейка будет пустой или заполнена будет символами то постоянно выдает эту ошибку. Код мой запускает цикл на поиск # или 2 затем добавляет выходные данные. Ошибка в след.   `int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[i].Text);`

```
            int summm = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
                for (int itt = 0; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
                {
                    int Totall2 = 0;
                int tt = listView1.Columns.Count - 6;
                string sd = null;
                for (int i = 2; i < tt; i++)
                {
                    Totall2 =
                    int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[i].Text);

                        switch (Convert.ToString(Totall2))
                    {
                        case "2":
                            sd = "н/у";
                            break;
                        case "#":
                            sd = "н/у";
                            break;

                    }
                    listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[summm - 5].Text = sd.ToString();
                }

            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#` - это же естественно не число. Проверяйте на его наличие, либо используйте `TryParse`, который сделает это за вас.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а если будет пустая ячейка

Comment: В чём смысл преобразоывавать текст в число (`int.Parse(...Text)`) и тут же обратно преобразовывать число в текст (`Convert.ToString`)?

Comment: Если будет пустая ячейка, то `TryParse` вернет `false`. То есть у вас должно быть что то по типу `if (int.TryParse(value, out num))`. Ну а так у вас костылей в коде уйма, советую от них избавится, тогда не будет таких проблем!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ знал бы как давно исправил

Comment: Можно нормальное решение опубликовать если не сложно без костылей :D

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как не преобразовывать ?

Comment: Никак. В данном случае преобразование совсем не нужно. Ведь вы не используете число. Просто пишите: `switch (listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[i].Text)`

Comment: Главное: перестаньте использовать графический компонент (ListView) как хранилище данных. Попробуйте вывести те же данные в консоль, с помощью `Console.WriteLine`. Как в этом случае будете хранить данные? Очевидно, в некой коллекции (скажем, `List<T>`). Соответственно, вся логика обработки данных будет использовать эту коллекцию. А уже потом готовые вычисленные/обработанные данные выводятся куда нужно: на консоль или в GUI (ListView).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за ваш ответ вы мне очень помогли )

Answer (score 1):

```
                int summm = listView1.Columns.Count - 1;
                for (int itt = 0; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
                {
                    int tt = listView1.Columns.Count - 6;
                    string sd = null;
                    for (int i = 2; i < tt; i++)
                    {
                        switch (listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[i].Text)
                        {
                            case "2":
                                sd = "н/у";
                                break;
                            case "#":
                                sd = "н/у";
                                break;
                        }
                        if (sd == null)
                        {
                            sd = "у";
                        }
                        listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[summm - 5].Text = sd.ToString();
                 }
```